# в str содержится обернутый набор элементов, при переборе, получаю их текстовое содержимое, отбираю весь текст до ":", как применить стили?

Tags: javascript

```
var str = $(".bx_catalog_item_container").find($(".bx_catalog_item_title")).children("a").each(function(ind, elem){

    var el = $(elem).text();
    var indexStr = el.indexOf(":");
    var changeStr = el.substring(0,indexStr);

});
```

Comment: блин, все перепробовал, через style,classList.add не применяется

Comment: `$(elem).addClass("myClass");`  и может `find(".bx_catalog_item_title")`?

Comment: `el.get(0).classList.add()`

Comment: в changeStr содержится набор элементов и мне нужно к ним применить класс именно после преобразование el.substring(0,indexStr)

Comment: в строке содержится набор элементов? Поработайте над формулировками.

Comment: в str содержится обернутый набор элементов, я их перебираю,  получаю их текстовое содержимое, отбираю весь текст до ":" и мне нужно сделать его жирным

Comment: Дополните, пожалуйста, Ваш вопрос путем его редактирования.

Comment: Не получается применить стили именно после этого метода var changeStr = el.substring(0,indexStr);

Comment: как к переменной changeStr  добавить css класс?

Comment: как Вы пытались их "применить"? Например, завернуть текст в таг `span` с атрибутом `class="myClass"`.

Comment: нет, я пытался так: changeStr.style.font-weight = "bold"; и аналогично через .classList.add()

Comment: `changeStr` - это строка. Классы css нельзя применять к строкам. Если вы хотите какой-то подстроке из элемента `elem` добавить какой-то класс, то либюо эту подстроку нужно вынести в отдельный элемент, либо добавлять css для всего `elem`

Answer (score 2):

```
$(".bx_catalog_item_container").find($(".bx_catalog_item_title")).children("a").each(function(ind, elem){
    var text = $(elem).text().split(':');
    text = '<b>'+text[0]+'</b>:'+text[1];
    $(elem).html(text);
});
```